# Change name of an x Packagist package

Tags: packagist

I would like to create a package for one of my github repositories on packagist.

Now I am offered a name when I submit it.

I don't understand how this name is suggested. My name on github is astridx and my first package started with vendor astridx. To keep it uniform I would like to use astridx everywhere. Do I have any influence on the name?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself. It was easy. I had to change the name in composer.json.